# Enzyme doesn't see all props of react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I have react component Button.js and it can receive few props: `type`, `onClick` and `text`. I am writing my tests to identify if component received props, but while writing tests with enzyme I can see that some props are undefined returned undefined even though I pass them.

Code of component and test is [here](https://gist.github.com/Mindaugas-Jacionis/21e9d8638254887befbd31ddbcee80a6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that you are passing props to the button but using the text prop as the actual text for the button.

Try testing if the text exists in the DOM(HTML). That should then pass fine.

Comment: `expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual('Test');` <<< turns out this is the way to test it